# Problem with parsing XML into table variable

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'm using the following code to read a SQL XML Variable into a table variable.  I am getting the following error.  " Incorrect syntax near '.'. "  Can't quite Figure it out

```
DECLARE @LOBS Table
(
LineGUID varchar(40)
)

DECLARE @lg xml
SET @lg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
  <LOB>
    <LineGuid>d6e3adad-8c53-4768-91a3-745c0dae0e08</LineGuid>
  </LOB>
  <LOB>
    <LineGuid>4406db8f-0d19-47da-953b-afc1db38b124</LineGuid>
  </LOB>
</Table>'

INSERT INTO @LOBS(LineGUID) 
SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(40)') 
FROM @lg.nodes('/Table/LOB/LineGuid') AS ParamValues(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to use a SELECT INTO statement?

```
SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(40)')
INTO @LOBS(LineGUID)
FROM @lg.nodes('...') AS ParamValues(ID)
```

Something like that?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: change the SELECT Statement to Read 
SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(40)') 
INTO @LOBS(LineGUID) 
FROM @lg.nodes('Table/LOB/LineGuid') AS ParamValues(ID) 

Now getting the error "Incorrect syntax near '@LOBS'"